# Android Studio 3.0: Floating Action Button OnClick not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make my Floating Action Button in Android Studio 3.0.1 move to a different activity. Everywhere I search, none of theme work. I am fairly new to android studio and Java. Could someone help? Thank you!

***add is the name of the activity I want to launch**

The code I've got so far is (off of sketchy website):

```js
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClick:setAction(".add", null).show();
            }
        });
```

And the error:

```js
5 errors

 FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: I don't have any, I cant figure out the code do do it... 

Comment: Hello @Simon, Just asking a plain question without any references wont help anybody understand. Please make sure to attach some screenshots and mention what you've tried and where you are stuck. This will provide better clarity to the person helping you. If you need more details on how to ask a good question, Please refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: edited. I hope this works

Comment: That is either `build` or `debug` output where exception is not provided. Provide `logcat` output you can select `Logcat` on bottom or if you don't have it enabled press `Alt` + `6` or `Cmd` + `6`

Answer (score 1):

To help you getting started, you can find documentation on how to add a floating button [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button). To make it start a new activity after cliking, add the instruction in the listener:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) 
   {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the Snackbar while using the  floating action Button.

Example->

```js
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Here's a Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});
```